# web service soap call - how to get returning parameter

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am creating web service. So I created this soapcall:

```
public function GetLogon($uzivatel, $heslo){
    $soap = new SoapClient('http://www.softhouse.cz/ezopconnector2/ezopconnector.asmx?wsdl');
    $params = array('uzivatel'=>$uzivatel, 'password'=>$heslo);
    $response = $soap->__soapCall("EzopLogon", array($params));
    var_dump($response);
}
```

call it in presenter like this, but it's not relevant I think:

```
$this->me->GetLogon("administrator", "a");
```

my problem is that this function should return me a session (of user).. does anybody know how can I get this session for future use? (for example for logout)

thanks a lot I am a novice, so dont yel at me :D

Update:

---

code for login:

```
public function GetLogon($uzivatel, $heslo){
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://www.softhouse.cz/ezopconnector2/ezopconnector.asmx?wsdl');
    $params = array('uzivatel'=>$uzivatel, 'heslo'=>$heslo);
    $this->session = $soapClient->__soapCall("EzopLogon", array($params));
    var_dump($this->session);
}
```

session saved as public variable in class:

```
public $session;
```

Code of function where session si required:

```
public function GetCtiSezSdruzAdd2(){
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://www.softhouse.cz/ezopconnector2/ezopconnector.asmx?wsdl');
    $params = array('Session'=>$this->session);
    return $soapClient->__soapCall("EzopCtiSeznamSdruzenychAdresaru", array($params));
}
```

and call in presenter:

```
    $this->me->GetCtiSezSdruzAdd2();
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to expect or return session with web services. Instead you of that you get user data and hit one more end point with token or some of the unique user property to logout

Comment: why you pass an argument called password which is not used in your wsdl ?! Look at the EzopLogon's input there is no argument called password !

Comment: @OmisBrown oh yes, thank you, I changed it... now I response to this request save to $session... and I want to call EzopCtiSeznamSdruzenychAdresaru function I put session as parameter, it gives me an error saying that UID property is no defined..

Comment: can you put some code to see !

Comment: @OmisBrown ok Iam editing my post..

Comment: @pajasv please one more thing , why you are passing the argument into an array called $params and when you are using the __soapCall you pass it again in another array ? 
It like you are doing  
$response = $soap->__soapCall("EzopLogon", array(array('arguments')));

Comment: @OmisBrown the post is updated.... yes, but i think its right, isnt it?... ive red it here: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Try to print the value of $this->Session in GetCtiSezSdruzAdd2() and see if it has the value that you want